# matrix addition java

Tags: java

I wrote this matrix addition program and I dont know why but I keep getting this two errors on lines 61 and 63 and i dont want to handle the exceptions but just throwing would do

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared
```

The code of the program is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
class Arr
{
    int r,c;
    int arr[][];

    Arr(int r,int c)
    {
        this.r=r;
        this.c=c;
        arr=new int[r][c];
    }

    int[][] getMatrix()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("enter element");
                arr[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    int[][] findsum(int a[][],int b[][])
    {
        int temp[][]=new int[r][c];
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
                temp[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        return temp;
    }

    void putmatrix(int res[][])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(res[i][j]+"\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}


class Matrixsum
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Arr obj1=new Arr(3,3);
        Arr obj2=new Arr(3,3);

        int x[][],y[][],z[][];
        System.out.println("\nEnter matrix 1");
        x=obj1.getMatrix();
        System.out.println("Enter matrix 2");
        y=obj2.getMatrix();
        z=obj1.findsum(x,y);
        System.out.println("the sum matrix is");
        obj2.putmatrix(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. getMatrix() is declared to throw IOException. Calls to getMatrix() in main() can generate IOExceptions, which are required to be caught by the function or rethrown. To solve the problem, you could declare main() to throw IOException.
2. The design of class `Arr` is a bit strange. Instead of using two redundant objects `obj1` and `obj2`, you should condense it to one object, say one called arrProcessor. So the calls would look like:

   ```
   x=arrProcessor.getMatrix();
   y=arrProcessor.getMatrix();
   z=arrProcessor.findSum(x,y);
   arrProcessor.putMatrix(z);
   ```

Even better, instead of using arrays, you should wrap the arrays in objects, say in a class called Matrix:

```
public class Matrix{
    int[][] values;
    int numRows, numCols;

    protected Matrix(){/*...*/}

    public static Matrix getMatrix(int nRows, int nCols){/*...*/}
    public static Matrix addMatrices(Matrix a, Matrix b) throws Exception {/*...*/}

    public void print(){/*...*/}
    public void plus(Matrix another) throws Exception {/*...*/}
}
```

So now the code would look like:

```
Matrix x,y,z;
x=Matrix.getMatrix(3,3);
y=Matrix.getMatrix(3,3);
z=x.plus(y);
z.print();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because getMatrix throws IOException which must be caught or declared as thrown by main.

In your case the simplest solution is to declare it on main.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
```

Comment: @user667405: if an answer is helpful, you can indicate that by upvoting it, and accepting it if it solved your problem. No need to leave a comment for that.

Answer (score 0):

hey i would suggest you this one.
http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

If you tired to write your own code with matrix, just download library I developed. It can add, multiply, invert, transpond, calculate determinant and solve linear systems.

please check: [Linear Math Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linearmath/)

This is open source you can download the source code too and look how in works.